# Compare mutiple images with one images

Tags: python, opencv3.0, opencv

I'm trying to compare one image with a folder full of images and trying to find an equal image, but I can't figure out on how to compare one image to a folder full of images

I tried making a listOfFiles with fnmatch and os but it only takes one of the few images.

```py
#import 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os, fnmatch

#Collects all images 
listOfFiles = os.listdir('./images')
pattern = "*.jpg"
for entry in listOfFiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            Allimages = ("images/" + entry)

#Define variables
upload = cv2.imread("images/img1.jpg")
duplicate = cv2.imread(Allimages)
#Checks if duplicate is duplicate 
if upload.shape == duplicate.shape:
    print("The images have same size and channels")
    difference = cv2.subtract(upload, duplicate)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(difference) 

    if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero (g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
        print("images are the same")

else:
    print("images are different")
```

Comment: `filenames = list(os.listdir(dirname))` or directly in loop `for filename in os.listdir(dirname): print("checking", filename)`

Comment: show in question how you used `fnmatch` and `os`

Comment: Where do I need to put that? (for the last comment.)

Comment: if you will assing filename to variable `Allimages = ` then you can't get more then one name - you have to keep it on list `Allimages = []` and in for-loop `Allimages.append( filename )`

Comment: when you will have list `Allimage` then you will need another `for`-loop to check every image. Or do all inside one for-loop.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do all inside `for` loop.

Probably you can compare images using only

```
if (upload == duplicate).all():
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import os

directory = './images'
upload = cv2.imread("images/img1.jpg")

for entry in os.listdir(directory):

    if entry.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif') ):

        fullname = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        print('fullname:', fullname)
        duplicate = cv2.imread(fullname)

        if upload.shape == duplicate.shape:
            print("The images have same size and channels")

            #difference = cv2.subtract(upload, duplicate)
            #b, g, r = cv2.split(difference) 
            #if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
            if (upload == duplicate).all():
                print("images are the same")

        else:
            print("images are different")
```

Comment: This gives mutiple errors, I believe there has to be a : after `if entry.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.jpeg') )` and it gives a _ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous._ on line 21

Comment: yes, I tested it after writing and now it should work.

Comment: to compare images should be `if (upload == duplicate).all():`